# git branch -a shows branch that can not be removed locally and is not present in remote

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a repo hosted in Github. The command `git branch -a` shows the following:

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/release-031
```

The (old) `release-031` is not present in the Github repo, and I can not delete it locally either:

```
$ git branch -d release-031
error: branch 'release-031' not found.
```

How can I remove these phantom old branch?

Comment: Try running `git remote update` followed by `git remote prune`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+remote+branch

Comment: `git branch -d -r origin/release-031`, `git fetch --prune`, `git remote prune origin`